# How do you exit from another method?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, methods, return

Is there anyway you can exit a method from another method like this?

```
            if (workisdone())
            Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Done");
            return.workisdone(); // or something like that?????
            DispatcherTimer timer = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
            timer.Stop();
            timer = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please explain your idea you want to implement.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. You want to return the value of another method if that value hit's a certain condition?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (workisdone())
{
    Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Done");
    return;
}
DispatcherTimer timer = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
timer.Stop();
timer = null;
```

Comment: The timer will never get stopped and disposed if `workisdone() == true`. Is that correct behavior?

Comment: @code4life Out of scope of the question I think. But good point!

Comment: Actually, I think it's in scope, because the memory will bleed rather fatally here.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have some multi threading happening somewhere, you can't actually enter the if block until you have already exited from the `workisdone()` method...

Answer (score 1):

```
    bool res = workisdone();
    if(res)
       return res;
   //rest of code here - any code below here will not run if workisdone() returns true
```

I would normally assume you stop a timer before exiting loop, but this code looks like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see what you're trying to do. So modify your code this way:

```
var isWorkDone = workisdone();

// i think, you should stop the timer no matter what the workisdone() result is.
DispatcherTimer timer = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
timer.Stop();
timer = null;

// pop the msg only if workisdone() == true
if (isWorkDone)
{
  Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Done");
}

return isWorkDone; // will return pass or fail.
```